# SWReveal TabBarController and Nav Bar issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

my issue can be seen in the below video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cql7r7b49lgffh9/navbarissue.mov

I have the following storyboard setup:[image]

To describe the problem in words...when the app loads it pushes revealviewcont>navcont>tabbarcont>navcont>firstviewcont. On the firstviewcont, the reveal menu button exists. Clicking this shows the slide out menu with numerous options in a table. Clicking the first cell returns you to the firstviewcont. However, when the firstviewcont is pushed from the menucont it creates a new navigation bar above the old one, thus rendering two nav bars. I assume this is because I'm going back through the stack, tabbarcont>navcont>firstviewcont. Attaching the segue to the firstview's nav controller is not supported, and attaching it to the firstviewcont does not display the Tab Bar.

I have tried hiding the navbar from viewwilldisappear and viewwillappear methods on the mentioned view controllers without success...how could I achieve returning to the firstviewcont while preserving the tab bar and displaying only one navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question by....reading the changelog on the SWRevealViewController.h file.

```
- Took a cleaner approach to storyboard support. SWRevealViewControllerSegue is now 
deprecated and you should use SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController and 
SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController instead.
```

Changing my segues to the new version of storyboard segue fixed my issue.

Thanks for a great subclass John LLuch!

Answer (score 0):

I tried SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController with identifier as "sw_front" and applied Embedded in navigationcontroller to view controller by removing old navigationcontroller then it works fine iOS 11. If you want navbar for front/center view add navcontroller to your view controller and connect segue to nav controller so that it displays nav bar either on front view or rear vc.